# Python 3: Removing an empty tuple from a list of tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a list of tuples that reads as such:

```
>>>myList
[(), (), ('',), ('c', 'e'), ('ca', 'ea'), ('d',), ('do',), ('dog', 'ear', 'eat', 'cat', 'car'), ('dogs', 'cars', 'done', 'eats', 'cats', 'ears'), ('don',)]
```

And I would like it to read as such:

```
>>>myList
[('',), ('c', 'e'), ('ca', 'ea'), ('d',), ('do',), ('dog', 'ear', 'eat', 'cat', 'car'), ('dogs', 'cars', 'done', 'eats', 'cats', 'ears'), ('don',)]
```

i.e. I would like to remove the empty tuples `()` from the list. While doing this I want to preserve the tuple `('',)`. I cannot seem to find a way to remove these empty tuples from the list.

I have tried `myList.remove(())` and using a for loop to do it, but either that doesn't work or I am getting the syntax wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: An important thing to note there is that empty tuples ``()`` evaluate to ``False`` in a boolean context (e.g. ``if my_tuple:``). Tuples containing only empty/falsy values (e.g. ``('',)`` or ``(None, ())``), however, evaluate to ``True``.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can filter 'empty' values:

```
filter(None, myList)
```

or you can use a list comprehension. On Python 3, `filter()` returns a generator; the list comprehension returns a list on either Python 2 or 3:

```
[t for t in myList if t]
```

If your list contains more than just tuples, you could test for empty tuples explicitly:

```
[t for t in myList if t != ()]
```

Python 2 demo:

```
>>> myList = [(), (), ('',), ('c', 'e'), ('ca', 'ea'), ('d',), ('do',), ('dog', 'ear', 'eat', 'cat', 'car'), ('dogs', 'cars', 'done', 'eats', 'cats', 'ears'), ('don',)]
>>> filter(None, myList)
[('',), ('c', 'e'), ('ca', 'ea'), ('d',), ('do',), ('dog', 'ear', 'eat', 'cat', 'car'), ('dogs', 'cars', 'done', 'eats', 'cats', 'ears'), ('don',)]
>>> [t for t in myList if t]
[('',), ('c', 'e'), ('ca', 'ea'), ('d',), ('do',), ('dog', 'ear', 'eat', 'cat', 'car'), ('dogs', 'cars', 'done', 'eats', 'cats', 'ears'), ('don',)]
>>> [t for t in myList if t != ()]
[('',), ('c', 'e'), ('ca', 'ea'), ('d',), ('do',), ('dog', 'ear', 'eat', 'cat', 'car'), ('dogs', 'cars', 'done', 'eats', 'cats', 'ears'), ('don',)]
```

Of these options, the `filter()` function is fastest:

```
>>> timeit.timeit('filter(None, myList)', 'from __main__ import myList')
0.637274980545044
>>> timeit.timeit('[t for t in myList if t]', 'from __main__ import myList')
1.243359088897705
>>> timeit.timeit('[t for t in myList if t != ()]', 'from __main__ import myList')
1.4746298789978027
```

On Python 3, stick to the list comprehension instead:

```
>>> timeit.timeit('list(filter(None, myList))', 'from __main__ import myList')
1.5365421772003174
>>> timeit.timeit('[t for t in myList if t]', 'from __main__ import myList')
1.29734206199646
```

Comment: How fast is `list(filter(None, myList))`?

Comment: @squiguy: `list(filter(None, myList))` is slower than the list comprehension, on Python 3. See http://ideone.com/xWcqgh

Comment: There is also `itertools.ifilter` it might be even faster.

Comment: @Akavall: no, `ifilter()` no longer exists in Python 3, because the built-in `filter()` replaced it. In Python 2, it is just as slow as the `list(filter(...))` version therefor.

Answer (score 7):

```
myList = [x for x in myList if x != ()]
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! Don't know how I didn't think of it before, but thanks very much.

Answer (score 3):

Use a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to filter out the empty tuples:

```
>>> myList = [(), (), ('',), ('c', 'e'), ('ca', 'ea'), ('d',), ('do',), ('dog', 'ear', 'eat', 'cat', 'car'), ('dogs', 'cars', 'done', 'eats', 'cats', 'ears'), ('don',)]
>>> myList = [x for x in myList if x]
>>> myList
[('',), ('c', 'e'), ('ca', 'ea'), ('d',), ('do',), ('dog', 'ear', 'eat', 'cat', 'car'), ('dogs', 'cars', 'done', 'eats', 'cats', 'ears'), ('don',)]
>>>
```

This works because empty tuples evaluate to `False` in Python.

Comment: Thanks! This is actually the answer I used in my code since it looks cleanest.

Comment: @ilikemustard - You're welcome!  However, if my answer was the one you used, then I ask that you please don't forget to [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235).  Accepting answers lets future people know that the question is answered.

Comment: Yeah good idea! I am new to asking questions so I'm still getting the hang of it. Though this answer answered my question perfectly, there was another more thorough answer that I think was slightly more helpful so I accepted that. Sorry to disappoint, and thanks a ton for the answer! Have a nice day.

Comment: Hey that's fine.  The important thing is that the question is answered.  Besides, I even think that Pieter's answer deserved the acceptance.  He clearly put in a lot more effort than I did.

Answer (score 2):

> Explicit is better than implicit

I find this one is more readable and not ambiguous by specifying clearly what function of the filter is. So clearly we want to remove those empty tuple which is `()`.

```
def filter_empty_tuple(my_tuple_list):
    return filter(lambda x: x != (), my_tuple_list)

# convert to list
def filter_empty_tuple_to_list(my_tuple_list):
    return list(filter(lambda x: x != (), my_tuple_list))
```

Perhaps it would be good if you don't convert them into a `list` and use it as `generator`.
See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47789/generator-expressions-vs-list-comprehension) when deciding which to use