# Remove Tuple if it Contains any Empty String Elements

Tags: python-3.x, list, tuples

There have been questions asked that are similar to what I'm after, but not quite, like [Python 3: Removing an empty tuple from a list of tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20413393/python-3-removing-an-empty-tuple-from-a-list-of-tuples), but I'm still having trouble reading between the lines, so to speak.

Here is my data structure, a list of tuples containing strings

```
data
>>[
('1','1','2'),
('','1', '1'),
('2','1', '1'),
('1', '', '1')
]
```

What I want to do is if there is an empty string element within the tuple, remove the entire tuple from the list.

The closest I got was:

```
data2 = any(map(lambda x: x is not None, data))
```

I thought that would give me a list of trues' and falses' to see which ones to drop, but it just was a single bool. Feel free to scrap that approach if there is a better/easier way.

Comment: If you can guarantee the only falsey elements in the tuples will be strings, you can get this down to `list(filter(all, data))`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `filter` - in the question you linked to `None` is where you put a function to filter results by. In your case:

```
list(filter(lambda t: '' not in t, data))
```

`t` ends up being each tuple in the `list` - so you filter to only results which do not have `''` in them.

Answer (score 2):

You can use list comprehension as follows:

```
data = [ ('1','1','2'), ('','1', '1'), ('2','1', '1'), ('1', '', '1') ]
data2 = [_ for _ in data if '' not in _]
print(data2)
```

**output:**

```
[('1', '1', '2'), ('2', '1', '1')]
```